# while loop ends at zero

Tags: node.js, mongoose, while-loop

I have while loop in my code and some if conditions in it. but it just do the first round. This loop is a part of a function. Here is my code for this part:

```
else{
            var i = 0;
            do{
                var resmedid = (result.media[i].mediaid);
                var len = result.media.length
                if(opts.medid1 == resmedid){
                    var query = {tokenid: opts.token1}
                    user.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$pull: {media: {_id: result.media[i]._id}}},function(err, result2){
                    if (err){
                        console.error(err);
                        callback(new Error('System Error'));
                        return;
                        }
                    else{
                        result = 'updated';
                        callback(null, result);
                        return;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                    }
                if (i == len){
                    console.log(i = len);
                        result = 'not match';
                        callback(null, result);
                        return;
                    }
                i++;
            }
            while(i < result.media.length);
        };
```

What this loop does is that it is looking if opts.medid1 is equal to a string in an array which is called result.media. reesult.media[i].mediaid are the ones that exist in my database and the opts.medid1 is the one I get by the url.

This is how my schema looklike:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid: {type: String, unique: true},
    tokenid: {type: String, sparse: true, default: null},
    media: [{
    mediaid: String,
    mediaurl: String
    }]},
    {versionKey: false}
    );
```

What am I doing wrong to cause my while loop stuck in first round which i is 0 in it??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the code exited on its first iteration (`i = 0`) was because of the `break` statement.

Based on your code above, this is how your code path would look like,

1. Go into the `do while loop`
2. Initialize some variables
3. Assuming condition `(opts.medid1 == resmedid)` is met, continue on.
4. Call `user.findOneAndUpdate` and since it is an async call, the code will move on without waiting for it to finish executing.
5. Code reads `break` statement and exits without finishing the first round of loop.

Not sure what the **break** statement's intention was but I suspect it could be just a copy-paste error mainly because it does not seem to fit into the code at all. Also due to the misaligned intentation the `break` statement does look like it belongs to the callback function of `user.findOneAndUpdate` thou.

I have re-indented your code, to make the `break` more distinguishable that it does not belongs to the callback.

```
do {
    var resmedid = (result.media[i].mediaid);
    var len = result.media.length
    if(opts.medid1 == resmedid) {
        var query = {tokenid: opts.token1}
        // Note: Async call, code will move on without waiting for it to finish
        user.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$pull: {media: {_id: result.media[i]._id}}},function(err, result2){
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                callback(new Error('System Error'));
                return;
            }
            else{
                result = 'updated';
                callback(null, result);
                return;
            }
        });
        // Note the break here. This is called right after user.findOneAndUpdate is called
        break;
    }
    if (i == len) {
                   ....
    }
    i++;
} while(i < result.media.length);
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: Thanks for answering me. the `break`  there is because I want it to get out of the loop if it found the match and deleted it. I commented all the if and else in the loop and just do   `console.log(i)`  and it still does not work!!

Comment: Let me know if it solves your problem. Happy to take another look if the issue is still there.

Comment: also it does not come out of loop!! if i just put `console.log(i)` in loop it just print 0!

Comment: Moving the break into the callback function will not work. I think your code should be doing something like, iterate 1 round, call do the async call, wait for its result. if not found, go onto the next one but if found then break the loop. What you are doing there is you are firing off 5 async call at 1 go to find and delete.

Comment: As this question is for finding out why your loop didn't stop... It is kind of difficult for me to derail the topic and talk about how you could sequentially perform async calls. Recommend you mark this as over and spawn another question on that topic?

Comment: I found the fault, I should put the `if(i == len)`  after while loop, I did that and it works fine :D, Thanks for your time.